# If isset userid is equal to 1?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have small issue! I current have a UserID number coming from a login page, Can I not do something like this?

This works:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
}
    include('../includes/navAdmin.inc.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: Login.php');
}
```

But I want to do something more like this to restrict links to certain users etc:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
}else if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"] === 1){ <---this one to give the "admin" the admin page etc
    include('../includes/navAdmin.inc.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: Login.php');
}
```

Seems like I can't or the syntax is wrong perhaps? Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure this works? You have a closing bracket immediately following your opening bracket for your first if statement

Comment: @thanksd it does, they just don't have anything inside the first conditional `if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
}`. all braces match.

Comment: @Fred-ii- not in the first example (which he says is working)

Comment: @thanksd ah ok. I didn't check that. I thought you were talking about the 2nd one.  You are right. +1 on your comment ;-)

Comment: @thanksd I've made an additional edit to my answer to outline that syntax error and for future readers, should the OP not modify their question, if that isn't their actual code. (I'm not kicking for points here) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to modify your code to check if it is set **and** equal to 1.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"]) && $_SESSION["UserID"] === 1)
```

rather than the `else if`.

Just set an `else` condition after that if it is not set or equal to 1.

On another note, add `exit;` after header. If you have more code below that, it way want to continue to execute.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

As per the manual:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

---

Sidenote: As spotted/stated in comments by `thanksd`. There is an extra brace here, if that is your actual code.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
}
    include('../includes/navAdmin.inc.php');
} // Right there
else {
    header('Location: Login.php');
}
```

and that would have thrown you an unexpected end of file notice having error reporting set to catch/display.

You may have meant to do:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
    include('../includes/navAdmin.inc.php');
}

else {
    header('Location: Login.php');
}
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thanks for your note regarding exit after header. I don't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Write your condition as below:-

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
    if($_SESSION["UserID"] === 1){
        include('../includes/navAdmin.inc.php'); die;
    }else{
         header('Location: Login.php'); die;
    }
}else{
    header('Location: Login.php'); die;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Fred -ii-'s answer is more accurate.